# How to search word on unix folders

Tags: unix

I am trying to find a word(case sensitive) in unix server recursively under all folders/files.
i am using below syntax, not sure if its right way of searching.

```
 grep -Rin "word" *
```

Comment: Are you trying to search file-contents for that word or file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `grep` recursively, you do not need a list of files at the end, in your case -- `*`.

Use `grep -Rin "word"` from the directory you want to begin your search from.

Alternatively, `find` command can be used.

`find <top_path> -type f | xargs grep -in "word"`.

top_path can be `.` or present working directory or a full path.  `-type f` only finds files to speed up the search.  `xargs` gives `find` results to `grep` as arguments.

Comment: will -Rin also take case sensitivity into consideration?

Comment: the 'i' option means that it will be case insensitive.  if case is important, do not use 'i'

Comment: tried using grep -Rin "word" and it didn't return any result. does it take that too long to return any result

Comment: no, the results start to appear pretty quickly.  be sure to run it from the top directory in the tree you are searching.  i'll also post an alternative method in the answer above.

Comment: @Zoom also, does "word" actually exist in any of your files?  perhaps `grep` actually did not find anything.  you could try it with a term that you know exists in at least one file.